# HTMLElement prototype method loses scope of 'this' to Window

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to modify the HTMLElement prototype to have a custom function in an instance of HTMLELement. I need for that function to be able to access the HTMLElement Instance's properties like the `tagName`. The problem is that inside the custom prototype function `this` points to the Window object instead of the HTMLElement instance. How can I achieve this?

```js
HTMLElement.prototype.doSomething = () => {
  console.log(this)
  // Here I need to do something like console.log(this.tagName)
} 

let elem = document.createElement('div')
elem.doSomething()
// -> Window Object, instead of HTMLElement Instance object.
```

Thank you

Comment: Arrow functions do not capture `this`. Use `function() {}` syntax instead.

Comment: You are totally right, thank you!